# Android - Check from position A (index) if postion B (index) is diagonal to it in a gridview layout regardless of proximity

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, matrix

If I have a position or row/column for both A and B positions, check to see if B is diagonal to A?

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

How do I check if for example if 5 is diagonal to 7?

Also if I check to see if 4 is diagonal 3, it shouldn't get a true return also?

Answer from below integrated in my situation.

My call on it from another function

```
!isDiagonal(goodguyposition, positionadd1)

public static boolean isDiagonal(int a, int b) 
    {
        // x = number of columns
        // y = number of rows
        // s = index start (1)
        // a = index of a
        // b = index of b

        int x = 11;
        //int y = 11;
        int s = 0;
        int ax = (s - a) % x, ay = (s - a) / x, bx = (s - b) % x, by = (s - b) / x;

        if ((ax == bx - 1 || ax == bx + 1) && (ay == by - 1 || ay == by + 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ive updated my answer with concrete implementation ...

Comment: Is there way to vote for two answers. Both of your answers are great! Just answer them in two different ways. Probably going to use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response cleaned for readability:

```
public static boolean isAdjacentDiagonal(int x, int s, int a, int b) {
    // x = number of columns
    // s = index start
    // a = index of a
    // b = index of b
    int ax = (a - s) % x, ay = (a - s) / x, bx = (b - s) % x, by = (b - s) / x;
    return (bx == ax - 1 || bx == ax + 1) && (by == ay - 1 || by == ay + 1);
}
```

With Math.abs and only if your index starts at 0:

```
public static boolean isAdjacentDiagonal(int x, int a, int b) {
    int ax = a % x, ay = a / x, bx = b % x, by = b / x;
    return Math.abs(ax - bx) == 1 && Math.abs(ay - by) == 1;
}

public static boolean isOneOfDiagonals(int x, int a, int b) {
    int ax = a % x, ay = a / x, bx = b % x, by = b / x;
    return a != b && Math.abs(ax - bx) == Math.abs(ay - by);
}
```

Comment: So I only need the number of columns(x) and not the number of rows(Y) for the formula? This is great.

Comment: What would the if condition look like in Java for this? Check my code above, is there better way of doing it?

Comment: I tested this works in most cases but it doesn't stop the case where if the diagonal if more then one diagonal. For example if A is 11 and B is 3 then that considers diagonal.

Comment: s = index start (1) What do you mean by index start? If the index starts from 0,1,2 or 1,2,3, or 2,3,4 is that what you mean?

Comment: yes it is! in general, index starts at 0 but in your case, starts at 1

Comment: Its not stopping from more then one adjacent diagonal. I'm not sure if I'm doing everything right. I posted my code and the call I'm doing on the Boolean.  I call on the function to see if it false because if it is diagonal then I don't want my function to do anything.  My index does start at 0 zero though in my real case. I'm also on 11 by 11 grid.

Comment: Please, give me a sample of arguments wich are not valid

Comment: The second function is exactly what I meant. Thank you. Your good at matrix. Trying to get solution similar to this question.  I need to know if index more then the adjacent surrounding boxes similar to this diagonal solution but regardless of diagonals, in every direction. The solution have isn't perfect, maybe you can help with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490520/android-how-to-find-adjacent-items-in-gridview-layout

Comment: Alex If you got a moment, I posted another type of question like the others, this has to deal with shortest path on a grid.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519752/android-java-shortest-path-from-two-indexes-on-gridview

Answer (score 1):

it's diagonal and adjacent if Math.abs( Ax - Bx ) ==1 && Math.abs( Ay - By ) == 1
where Ax and Bx is the column value of A and B respectively
  and Ay and By is the row value of A and B respectively

checking for a difference of exactly +-1 in both directions limits it to the adjacent squares that are not in the same row/col.. which are the adjacent diagonals

if you want any diagonal , then use Math.abs(Ax-Bx)==Math.abs(Ay-By)

if you don't want to include the case where A=B, you have to check for that separately