# How to get the adjacent item position in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, position

I have a grid view in Android and I want to fetch the adjacent list item position I have attached an image to make my doubt clear

[image: Here]

Suppose I clicked on item "5", I can easily get the position of this item but then I want to get the position of item 2, 4, 8, 6 only (0, 3, 7, 9 not included) I have checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490520/android-how-to-find-adjacent-items-in-gridview-layout) but I am not able to get what I really want from as final output.

Comment: Could you post your code? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: I was doing it with table layout but it didn't work for me so I thought to do it with GridView I don't have code, all I want is logic to find the adjacent positions my logic is 
I can get the adjacent positions of a particular item by incrementing and decrementing the 1 from current position but how to achieve same for upper and below position

Comment: what do u really want as final output?

Comment: `I don't have code, all I want is logic` You're playing with fire, on this site...

Comment: I have attached an image with my question take item "five" as starting position now I want to get the position of  2,4,8,6 item which are adjacent to item 5